# fwrite o fopen añaden una línea en blanco al principio del archivo. PHP

Tags: php

El resultado de este código devuelve un txt con un salto de línea al inicio. No tiene sentido porque el fichero no existe y lo abro con 'w' que sitúa el puntero al principio. ¿alguna idea? ya hasta estoy pensando que la función fwrite, fopen o fclose tienen algún bug.
Gracias.

```
    $myFile = fopen('prueba.txt', 'w');
    fwrite($myFile, trim('holaaaaaaa'));
    fclose($myFile);

    header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . utf8_decode('prueba.txt'));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("prueba.txt"));
    readfile("prueba.txt");
    unlink("prueba.txt");
    exit;
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿Podrías compartir el archivo PHP completo para poder revisarlo? Tiene toda la pinta de que el script no comienza con un `<?php` o hay algo entre el código que genera ese retorno del carro. He reproducido tu código y el contenido del archivo se me ha descargado correctamente.

Comment: Una captura de pantalla de la salida ayudaría a entender dónde aparece el salto de línea.

Comment: Tu código actualmente como está, NO PRODUCE UN SALTO DE LÍNEA. Por lo que no podemos ver el problema que tienes realmente, por favor, agrega todo el código relacionado con este proceso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las cabeceras son sumamente delicadas. Cuando trabajes con ellas evita cualquier salida por pantalla. Simplemente el espacio en blanco que tienes antes del primer `header` podría estar escribiendo algo antes de la salida.

También, para garantizar que se ha limpiado/vaciado el buffer de salida, conviene que pongas `ob_clean()` y `flush()`.

Así debería funcionar:

```
<?php
  $fileName='prueba.txt';
  $myFile = fopen($fileName, 'w');
  fwrite($myFile, trim('holaaaaaaa'));
  fclose($myFile);
  header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . utf8_decode($fileName));
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileName));
  ob_clean();
  flush();
  readfile($fileName);
  unlink($fileName);
  exit;
?>
```

**Resultado:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: mil gracias, con eso funcionó! eres un crack